# Why does composedPath throw an exception when an attribute does not exist, but works when it does exist?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have an event listener for `click` events on the `document` and I am using [**`composedPath`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/composedPath) to determine if anything in the path includes a certain attribute.

If something in the path **does** include an attribute I listen for then all is well and everything works.

However, if something in the path **does not** include an attribute I listen for then it throws an exception:

> "Uncaught TypeError: el.hasAttribute is not a function"

Here is a fiddle showing this:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const includesAttribute = event.composedPath().some((el) => el.hasAttribute('my-attribute'));
  console.log(`has attribute: ${includesAttribute}`);
});
```

```html
<button my-attribute>click me, I log true and work fine</button>

<br/>

<button other-attribute>click me, I throw an exception because I don't have the attribute</button>
```

Why do I get an exception only when the attribute does not exist? Shouldn't the `hasAttribute` method always be available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [`document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) does not have the method `getAttribute`. Your call to `some` is getting all the way to `document` when it doesn't find anything; see the logging of `nodeName` here:

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const includesAttribute = event.composedPath().some((el) => {
    console.log(el.nodeName);
    return el.hasAttribute('my-attribute');
  });
  console.log(`has attribute: ${includesAttribute}`);
});
```

```html
<button my-attribute>click me, I log true and work fine</button>

<br/>

<button other-attribute>click me, I throw an exception but now you can see why</button>
```

Just add a guard:

```
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    const includesAttribute = event.composedPath().some((el) => el.hasAttribute && el.hasAttribute('my-attribute'));
    console.log(`has attribute: ${includesAttribute}`);
});
```

```js
document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  const includesAttribute = event.composedPath().some((el) => el.hasAttribute && el.hasAttribute('my-attribute'));
  console.log(`has attribute: ${includesAttribute}`);
});
```

```html
<button my-attribute>click me, I log true and work fine</button>

<br/>

<button other-attribute>click me, I do not throw an exception anymore</button>
```